# How to create virtual column using MySQL SELECT?

Tags: php, mysql, select

If I do SELECT a AS b and b is not a column in the table, would query create the "virtual" column?

in fact, I need to incorporate some virtual column into the query and process some information into the query so I can use it with each item later on.

Comment: I've read the question a few times and there must be something I'm missing. Could you clarify a bit exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: Imagine the query as array of rows and columns. Usually, I just inherit columns from the table structure by simple SELECT * FROM, but now, I'd need to insert my own column to it.

Comment: maybe you should take _one_ look at the documentation..

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT id, email, IF(active = 1, 'enabled', 'disabled') AS account_status FROM users
```

This allows you to make operations and show it as columns.

EDIT:

you can also use joins and show operations as columns:

```
SELECT u.id, e.email, IF(c.id IS NULL, 'no selected', c.name) AS country
FROM users u LEFT JOIN countries c ON u.country_id = c.id
```

Comment: This post moves my knowledge of simple mysql statements a way forward :) , does it mean I can create ANY "column"??

Comment: But you can't use this new column to do operations or new IF evaluations... or yes?

Comment: You can use it to filter rows. Instead of putting the condition into the WHERE clause though you have to put it into a HAVING claus:
HAVING country='Germany'
for example.

Answer (score 73):

Try this one if you want to create a virtual column "age" within a select statement:

```
select brand, name, "10" as age from cars...
```

Comment: Good trick. Simple, but I had never tried that before. This was exactly what I was wondering! :D

Comment: Here is a little complicated trick for working with another tables in the same mysql query:
SELECT tpt.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM places WHERE tpt.id=places.type) as obj_count  FROM `places_types` as tpt ORDER BY tpt.name ASC LIMIT ?,?

Comment: This is an especially good trick to use when creating unions where it is advantageous to know which part of the union a row came from. Just put a different constant into each select that identifies which block the row came from. And a million-and-one other uses.

Answer (score 14):

You can add virtual columns as

```
SELECT '1' as temp
```

But if you tries to put where condition to additionally generated column, it wont work and will show an error message as the column doesn't exist.

We can solve this issue by returning sql result as a table.ie,

```
SELECT tb.* from (SELECT 1 as temp) as tb WHERE tb.temp = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

SELECT only retrieves data from the database, it does not change the table itself.

If you write

```
SELECT a AS b FROM x
```

"b" is just an alias name in the query. It does not create an extra column. Your result in the example would only contain one column named "b". But the column in the table would stay "a". "b" is just another name.

I don't really understand what you mean with "so I can use it with each item later on". Do you mean later in the select statement or later in your application. Perhaps you could provide some example code.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a CASE statement, like

```
SELECT name
       ,address
       ,CASE WHEN a < b THEN '1' 
             ELSE '2' END AS one_or_two
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax would create an alias for a as b, but it wouldn't have scope beyond the results of the statement. It sounds like you may want to create a [VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)

Answer (score 0):

See [MariaDB Docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/#:%7E:text=Values%20for%20VIRTUAL%20generated%20columns,column%27s%20value%20is%20not%20generated). Virtual columns are create by adding the keyword `VIRTUAL` to the column while adding an expression just before that. The good thing: you can add an index to the virtual column. If you need the actual values and are concerned about speed over storage use a `PERSISTENT` column.