# How to add the one more parameter in array using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one array in this array i want to add one more parameter, i don't how to add one more parameter in this array. please any one help me

***model***

```
  public function android_memberList($mobile)
    {
        $this->db->select('new_student.student_id, new_student.firstName, new_student.user_type');
        $this->db->from('new_student');
        $this->db->where('fatherMobile', $mobile['mobile']);
        $query2 = $this->db->get();

        # result_array is used to convert the data into an array
        $result_new_student = $query2->result_array(); 
        print_r($result_new_student);

    }
```

***`print_r($result_new_student);`  i have like this array***

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [student_id] => 1
            [firstName] => janarthan
            [user_type] => Student
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [student_id] => 2
            [firstName] => Santanu
            [user_type] => Student
        )

)
```

In this array we have to add one more parameter, that parameter should come in all array object

***Expected Results***

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [student_id] => 1
                [firstName] => janarthan
                [user_type] => Student
                [status] => "Verified"
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [student_id] => 2
                [firstName] => Santanu
                [user_type] => Student
                [status] => "Verified"
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1.*** Add `status` also in `select` query like below:-

```
$this->db->select('new_student.student_id, new_student.firstName, new_student.user_type,new_student.status');
```

***2.*** As you said `status` column doesn't exist then:-

```
foreach($result_new_student as $key=> $val){
  $result_new_student[$key]['status'] = 'Verified';
}
```

So code need to be like this:-

```
public function android_memberList($mobile){
    $this->db->select('new_student.student_id, new_student.firstName, new_student.user_type');
    $this->db->from('new_student');
    $this->db->where('fatherMobile', $mobile['mobile']);
    $query2 = $this->db->get();

    //result_array is used to convert the data into an array
    $result_new_student = $query2->result_array(); 
    foreach($result_new_student as $key=> $val){
      $result_new_student[$key]['status'] = 'Verified';
    }
    print_r($result_new_student);

}
```

***3.*** Once Use [Virtual column concept](https://stackoverflow.com/a/455266/4248328) and check:-

```
$this->db->select('new_student.student_id, new_student.firstName, new_student.user_type,"Verified" as status');
```

Comment: @subikshanM  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 4):

Use Like This run foreach and put this **$result_new_student[$key]['status'] = 'Verified';**

```
public function android_memberList($mobile)
    {
        $this->db->select('new_student.student_id, new_student.firstName, new_student.user_type');
        $this->db->from('new_student');
        $this->db->where('fatherMobile', $mobile['mobile']);
        $query2 = $this->db->get();

        # result_array is used to convert the data into an array
        $result_new_student = $query2->result_array(); 
        print_r($result_new_student);
        foreach($result_new_student as $key=>$result){
        $result_new_student[$key]['status'] = 'Verified';
        print_r($result_new_student); 
     }

    }
```

now in **print_r($result_new_student);** you will see extra **status** field

Comment: Without loop we can do or not?

Comment: For my requirement no need to use any loop,just i want to add one parameter means enough

Comment: if you want status field in every sub array ...then my way you should use loop

Answer (score 3):

You should change your select statement to:

`$this->db->select('new_student.student_id, new_student.firstName, new_student.user_type,"Verified" as status');`

Answer (score 3):

Just add like this :-

```
foreach($result_new_student as &$value)
{
    $value['status'] = "Verified";
}
```

Note that you have to add **&** before $value in foreach($result_new_student as **&**$value) to add 'status' actually.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
foreach( $result_new_student as $key=>$value ){ $result_new_student[$key]['status'] = "Verified"; } print_r($result_new_student);
```