# I don't know how to write a query to display some specific information

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to display some information from a SQL database and I don't know exactly how to write the query. I have a table which contains the "name" and the "studentship" of some students. What I have to do is to display the name, the studentship's value and to add another column(alias "Place") which contains the text "first" for the ones who have the studentship equal to 300, "second" for another studentship values. How can I do this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by: `"second" for another ones`?

Comment: For another studentship values; excepted "300"

Comment: It's still unclear. Please edit your question to show four rows from the students table and the result you want, based on these four rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT NAME, STUDENTSHIP, IF(STUDENTSHIP = 300, 'first', 'second') FROM TABLE
```

Related question:

[How to create virtual column using MySQL SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455261/how-to-create-virtual-column-using-mysql-select)

Answer (score 1):

You'll use a [CASE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) for your `place` field:

```
 SELECT name, 
     studentship, 
     CASE WHEN studentship=300 THEN 'first' WHEN studentship = <another one?> THEN 'second' END as place
 FROM yourtable;
```