# What is the right way to make a database searchable?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to make my database searchable. Some of my tables are products, categories, subCategories manufacturedYear, model, brands. I'm using  "%LIKE%" on my query and then union on tables. I get a result back, but one of the problems I cannot get the table name. One solution I thought of is creating a searchable table with 4 columns:

id, searchable term (it could be a sku,category ,subcategory etc ) and ID of the searchable term.

Comment: `UNION ALL SELECT 'mytable' AS tablename, term FROM ...`  You can put a simple string value in with a virtual field in each sub select of the union.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

`...UNION ALL SELECT 'mytable' AS tablename, term FROM mytable ...` Basically, you can put a simple string value in with a virtual field in each sub select of the union.   In this case I just called it `tablename` with a value of `"mytable"` the name of this example table.

So each row in `mytable` will have a field added named `tablename` with a string value of `mytable`.  Then as you union the results, each result set (Sub-Select) could have a different string value (in `tablename`) in the query for their respective tables.

You can also refer to this post which is specifically on "virtual columns"

[How to create virtual column using MySQL SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455261/how-to-create-virtual-column-using-mysql-select)

I don't know if I would say this is the "Right" way, but it will surly work.

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using UNION already, why not just add the name of the table being queried as a column in each UNIONed subquery, like :

```
SELECT 'table1' AS table_name, id, field1, field2
FROM table1
WHERE value LIKE ?
UNION
SELECT 'table2' AS table_name, id, field11, field12
FROM table2
WHERE value LIKE ?
UNION
...
```

When you get the data, you can get the name of the table from where each record was returned by checking column table_name.

NB : it would also be a good idea to return the primary key of each row, to make possible further requests easier.